# Not getting the correct address from geocoder.getFromLocation()

Tags: android, geocoding

I'm using this code, but it's not properly getting the results

```
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this.getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());

List<Address> addresses1 = geocoder.getFromLocationName ("Postal code", 1);

if(!addresses1.isEmpty()) {
    Address obj1 = addresses1.get(0);

    List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(obj1.getLatitude(), obj1.getLongitude(), 1);
}
```

Comment: Please give futher information on how the results are not properly. What is the output ? What should be the output etc...

Answer (score 0):

I think, it will be better if you use a web service for getting location information.

Below is a sample PHP code for getting location information.

```
$lat=$_POST["lat"];

$lng=$_POST["lng"];

$url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng='.trim($lat).','.trim($lng).'&sensor=false';

$json = @file_get_contents($url);
$data=json_decode($json);
$status = $data->status;
if($status=="OK")
echo $data->results[0]->formatted_address;
else
echo "NODATA";
```